# virsh: VM console does not show any output

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a VM which I can start with `virsh`. According to `virsh dumpxml VM1`, this is the allocated pty:

```
<serial type='pty'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/6'/>
  <target port='0'/>
  <alias name='serial0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/6'>
  <source path='/dev/pts/6'/>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
  <alias name='serial0'/>
</console>
```

The VM is running:

```
# virsh list
 Id Name                 State
----------------------------------
  7 VM1                  running
```

Inside the VM, this is the grub configuration:

```
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.24-28-virtual root=UUID=7a1685b9-ecc8-4b70-932c-459a6faac07d ro quiet splash console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600n8
```

And this is the command line launched by virsh to start the VM:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.12 -enable-kvm -m 256 -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -name VM1 -uuid 47ff6ec2-a748-4738-16b9-2ffe5780e456 -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/VM1.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=utc -boot c -drive file=/var/VMs/VM1.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,boot=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -device virtio-net-pci,vlan=0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:12:34:50,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -net tap,fd=64,vlan=0,name=hostnet0 -chardev pty,id=serial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=serial0 -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -k de -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
```

But if I connect with `virsh console VM1`, or I do `cat /dev/pts/6`, nothing is shown in the VM console.

Is there something else that I must consider?

### UPDATE

I have two VMs, one started directly with `kvm`, the other via `virsh`. The one started directly has a working console. I have verified the open files in both cases:

```
root@host1:~# lsof | grep 25093 | grep dev
kvm       25093         root  DEL       REG                0,4                3758780 /dev/zero
kvm       25093         root  DEL       REG                0,4                3758779 /dev/zero
kvm       25093         root  DEL       REG                0,4                3758777 /dev/zero
kvm       25093         root    0u      CHR              136,3         0t0          6 /dev/pts/3
kvm       25093         root    1u      CHR              136,3         0t0          6 /dev/pts/3
kvm       25093         root    2u      CHR              136,3         0t0          6 /dev/pts/3
kvm       25093         root    3u      CHR             10,232         0t0       8025 /dev/kvm
kvm       25093         root    7u      CHR             10,200         0t0       4983 /dev/net/tun
root@host1:~# lsof | grep 8341 | grep dev
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu  DEL       REG                0,4                9743486 /dev/zero
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu  DEL       REG                0,4                9743485 /dev/zero
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu  DEL       REG                0,4                9743483 /dev/zero
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu    0r      CHR                1,3         0t0       4640 /dev/null
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu    4u      CHR                5,2         0t0       4897 /dev/ptmx
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu    5u      CHR             10,232         0t0       8025 /dev/kvm
kvm        8341 libvirt-qemu   64u      CHR             10,200         0t0       4983 /dev/net/tun
```

As you can see, in one of the VMs (the wrong one), there are no file descriptors 1 & 2, and file descriptor 0 is redirected to /dev/null. That is the problem I guess.

The question is, how do I tell virsh not to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to hit "enter" a couple of times, to get the login prompt?

Comment: yes, i have, but there is no reaction. Even during the startup phase (I connect to the pty immediately after starting up the VM) I see no grub startup, and no linux boot messages. I think the VM is running fine, but I can not access it from the outside. I need to debug it (the network is not yet working), that is why I need console access.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<serial type='pty'>
  <target port='0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty'>
  <target type='serial' port='0'/>
</console>
```

This is what I normally add to the VMs definition, using `virsh edit`
Then `console=ttyS0` appended in the VM's kernel line in grub.conf

Never failed me so far

Comment: What is the command that you use to create the vm? I use the following: `virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n VM1 -r 256 --vcpus=1 --vnc --noautoconsole --os-type linux --accelerate --network=bridge:eth0,model=virtio -m 52:54:00:12:34:50 -k de --import --nographics --disk /var/VMs/VM1.qcow2`

Comment: to tell you the truth, I don't use `virt-install` at all. virt-manager is my usual tool

Comment: The problem was somewhere else, but thanks to your hints, I found it. Using virt-manager allowed me to open a VNC connection and I saw that it is not booting at all, because I did not specify in the --disk parameter that this is a qcow2 disk image. Aparently this can not be automatically inferred - even though the extension should be a good hint?. The command must be extended with `--disk path=$vm_drive,format=qcow2`

Comment: In Linux extensions are meaningless, just a part of the filename

Comment: Sure, but it would be very strange to suffix a python script with `.sh` or a bash script with `.py` (and would probably not work in some cases: you can not import a python module which does not end in .py for example)

Comment: that's just done for convenience, nothing to prevent a .sh file to be executed as a python script, if the hashbang is correct

Comment: Not only convenience: the import mechanism in python (for example) **only** works with files ending in `.py`. If you want another suffix, you will need quite a bit of hacking around. The same is true for other tools. The OS does not enforce extensions, but some tools do.

Comment: That is specific to python, not Linux in general.

Comment: Sure, which shows that extensions have sometimes meaning, *even* in a linux environment, which shows that the qcow2 format *could* be inferred from the .qcow2 extension even without specifying it manually, **if the tool was so implemented**, which is what I was assuming all along (and was obviously wrong), mainly because I did not know that there was a (strange?!) syntax to specify the format of the disk image. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17):

Working example of using Debian jessie as host and guest operating system.

1. create a VM using virt-install or virt-manager
   In any case you will get serial console statements added to VM.xml file
2. in guest VM run the following

   ```
    systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
    systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   ```
3. in guest VM in `/etc/default/grub` replace

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
    #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
   ```

by

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0"
    GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
```

4. in guest VM run the following

   ```
    guest# update-grub
   ```
5. the VM console for running VM can be get by

   ```
    host# virsh console VM
   ```

or start the VM with console attached

```
    host# virsh start VM --console
```

Sources:

- [0pointer.de systemd for Administrators, Part XVI](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html)
- [keypressure.com Testing libvirt over TLS](http://www.keypressure.com/blog/testing-libvirt-over-tls/)

Comment: Still working 100% on Stretch

Comment: What is the purpose of `tty0` and `serial`? It works with just `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"` and `GRUB_TERMINAL="console"` in my case. I couldn't find explanation in the sources.

Comment: Just step 1 and 2 are sufficient. No need to update your grub configuration. I just tested this on both Debian buster and bullseye.

Comment: this worked for me like a charm !
I'm using CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) for the host and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS for the guest VM

Answer (score 6):

I've found the most applicable answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909617/libvirt-virsh-console-no-response):

Suppose your virtual domain is `myGuest`, your preferred editor is `vi`, and your guest is installed with `grub2` and uses `systemd`. If the last assumption is not true, you might have a look at [Working with the Serial Console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/working_with_the_serial_console).

First, install `libguestfs-tools` on the host: `sudo apt install libguestfs-tools`. You will need this when working with headless guests.

Second, shut down your guest: `virsh shutdown myGuest`.

Next, mount the virtual disk: `guestmount -d myGuest -i /mnt` (or use any other existing directory as mountpoint). Now in `/mnt` you should be able to see the filesystem of the guest.

With `grub2` and `systemd`, you only have to modify the grub configuration: `vi /mnt/etc/default/grub`, and modify like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='console=tty0 console=ttyS0,19200n8'
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=19200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

As you will have to run `update-grub` on the guest, for the first start you have to also modify `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Find the default boot menu item and append the console information to the `linux` entry to look similar to

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic root=UUID=76f3e237-d791-4e9d-8ad7-fe5c9165ae55 ro console=ttyS0,19200 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,19200
```

Maybe you need root privileges to mount and edit the files.

Now restart the guest and start the virtual console:

```
virsh start myGuest && virsh console myGuest
```

You should see the kernel log and then a login prompt. After logging in, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 5):

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

has been sufficient for an Ubuntu guest (20.04), VM been initialized with virt-manager.

No need to change GRUB configuration entries, nor adding `serial`/`console` to the virsh XML file.

Comment: This also works on Debian (buster, bullseye).

Comment: Also works on an Ubuntu 22.04 guest. No other changes needed on host or guest.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
```

is good but i think You have to add sth to grub configuration to make console work before service serial-getty starts